# Passing Variable To Function Not Working

Tags: php

I am trying to pass a variable say `$q1` in PHP function like this:

```
function xyz()
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Terms as tag,count FROM freq where type like '%".$q1."%'  order  by count desc limit 50"); 
}
```

But it is throwing an error that `$q1` is undefined. I did also like this:

```
function xyz($q1)
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Terms as tag,count FROM freq where type like '%".$q1."%'  order  by count desc limit 50"); 
}
```

But still throwing the same error. What is wrong?

Comment: Please show some real code and the exact error you're getting

Comment: can you post the entire code ?

Comment: Did you really pass value for $q1 variable?

Comment: function xyz($q1) {your query}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
function xyz() { ... }
```

to:

```
function xyz($q1) { ... }
```

Then remember to actually pass `$q1` to the function:

```
xyz($q1);
```

Comment: @JensonMJohn, The last part of the answer is probably the most enlightening for the OP.

Comment: Yeah I mentioned as a comment to Qn. My first comment here was before your edit. It seems fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Terms as tag,count FROM freq where type like '%".$q1."%'  order  by count desc limit 50");
```

It has a reserve keyword count, so if you have column in the table as count then use as

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `Terms` as `tag`,`count` FROM `freq` where `type` like '%".$q1."%'  order  by count desc limit 50");
```

Also make sure that the value $q1 is available in your query, or in otherwords make sure to pass the value in the function.

Comment: Thats another issue, it needs to be passed in the function, but query does not look good. Since he is using count, but if trying to use the function count() then the way its done is wrong. If count is a part of the table then he needs to use `count`